# Unable to boot Windows after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have a laptop on which Windows 8 is already installed in UEFI mode.
Now I installed Kubuntu 14.04 onn that machine in Legacy mode. Now I have an issue. If I selected Legacy mode in BIOS the machine automatically boots to Kubuntu and if I select UEFI in BIOS it automatically boots to Windows.
How can I access both OSes without changing BIOS? I want to select the which OS to boot from the grub itself.

When I installed and ran `boot-repair` it showed an error saying run this application in UEFI mode to resolve this issue, but I cannot load Kubuntu in UEFI mode.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is not possible to load your different OS in your configuration. Either all UEFI or all LAGACY installed OS will be selectable in one way.
You need to install Ubuntu in UEFI or install Windows in LEGACY.
Please look for solutions for running Ubuntu in UEFI.